# get request for a website in a php script

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-get, get-request

I want to get request in a website like that

```
$id = "something";
$response = http_get("http://example.com?id=$id, array("timeout"=>1), $out);
```

I don't find how exactly I can use http_get

I've tried with file_get_contents, it is working like

```
$out = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com?id=something");
```

but I want it like that

```
$out = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com?id=$id");
```

this one is not working

Comment: Have you seen manual page for [http_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php)?

Comment: I saw it but didn't handle anyway

Comment: Perhaps try this `http_get("http://example.com?id=$id", array("timeout"=>1), $out);` *note:* a syntax error.

Comment: What is it you want (what do you mean by "response"). Do you want the head, the body, the head+body or the raw network response (could be gziped)?

Comment: I just want to body, I just tried what I see in manual page

Comment: it said Call to undefined function http_get()

Comment: Have you installed the HTTP extension?

Comment: I ve added it but still not working, I m using wamp btw

Comment: Check, if the extension is loaded, what is the result of `extension_loaded('HTTP')` ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I got it to work was using the code below.

```
$out = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com?id=".$id);
```

This will concatenate the $id variable contents onto the end of the url to request.